# Creating a new process during run in Simpy taking more time than the real-time via a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, runtime-error, real-time, simpy

My aim is to use simpy (3.0.10) RealtimeEnvironment with strick=True and be able to organise & control processes during continuous simulation. 
By using threads I will be able to model more extensive outside simpy and keep the realtime part small and fast.

But causing delays is resulting into: 
**"RuntimeError: Simulation too slow for real time"**

*Little excercise:*
- aprocess = class with simple yield timeout
- mainprocess with task=aprocess plus print env.now
- Execute mainprocess
- Next create a thread in mainprocess
- Daemonize the thread to let simpy continue
- Start thread taking more time than the real-time step
- Return when ready

I can't get this to work so apparently I'm doing something wrong here.
Looking forward to further insights with your help.

Here is the code:

```
import simpy
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# define a simple timeout process class
class aprocess(object):
    def __init__(self, env, name = 'aname'):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name


    def execute(self):
            while True: # repeat each run step
                print self.name, 'status now: %d at yield 1' %self.env.now
                yield self.env.timeout(5)
                print self.name, 'status now: %d at yield 2' %self.env.now
                yield self.env.timeout(2)

# define the main process class
class mainprocess(object):    
    def __init__(self, env, name = 'aname'):
        self.env = env
        self.name = name

    def printstatus(self):
        while True:
            print ('status now: %d' %self.env.now)
            yield self.env.timeout(1)

    def newtask(self, newTaskname = 'newtask'):
#        Task2name= str(raw_input('give a name for task2:'))
        # this will cause the function to delay longer than accepted by simpy for realtime:
        sleep(3)
        self.newTaskname=newTaskname
        newTask=aprocess(self.env, self.newTaskname)
        self.env.process(newTask.execute())
        print 'THREAD: new Task process created'

    def execute(self):
        t = None
#        processes are events to so they can call other processes:
        self.env.process(self.printstatus())
        Task1=aprocess(self.env, 'Task1')
        self.env.process(Task1.execute())
        print 'MAINPROCESS: Task 1 process created)'
        yield self.env.timeout(6)
        print "creating first thread"
        t=Thread(target=self.newtask())
        t.deamon = True # Daemonize thread
        t.start()
        while self.env.now<20:
            if not t.is_alive:  #check if completed
                print 't.is_alive=flase: tread completed'
                t.join()  #not shure if this is requried, is_alive already activates the thread
            yield self.env.timeout(1)


#run the simulation
env1 = simpy.rt.RealtimeEnvironment(initial_time=0, factor=1.0, strict=True)
Maintask = mainprocess(env1, 'Mainproc')
Mainproc = env1.process(Maintask.execute())
env1.run(until=Mainproc)
```

Comment: Are you running into the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)?

Comment: Just reading about it: I guess that could be the case indeed.

Comment: It's definitely a sneaky little issue you have to be careful with when trying to do threads in python. It's pretty common for a program that should theoretically benefit massively from multi threading  actually slow down.

Comment: Indeed Benjamin, thanks. Quickly learning that: Use threads for concurrent I/O, and multi-processes for parallel computation.
The huge benefit I see with the threads is the ability to share data real-time while processes seem rather separate.
As you can see a raw_input is in the comment. Could threads be solved (reading about switching threads..) be the solution to this?  And should I  better move to processes for the sleep(3) case.
Some quick guidance example I would highly appreciate.